# New profile pages are out - bugs and feedback master list

Tags: discussion, profile-page

Update:

Thanks for all the feedback and bug reports! I am locking this thread so people don't keep answering it when we no longer monitor it.

If you see a bug or want to raise a feature request, please do so in the usual manner, as a new question.

---

Some of you may have noticed that [we just launched](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-on/) the [new profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244238/profile-page-makeover-part-3-the-prototype-returns) and [activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features) pages that we have been talking about for a while now on [most Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed).

Most? Well, yes, the new design is dependent on a SE network-wide update (a new base css framework) that the design team have been working on. This is an ongoing effort and we will be launching the new pages as sites are moved to the new design.

You've all been hugely helpful already - much of what we love most in here came from [feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features) and [suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244238/profile-page-makeover-part-3-the-prototype-returns) you gave us on Meta.

But it's *possible* that it's not *quite* perfect yet. If you find any bugs and have any feedback to give, please post these as answers to this post.

Just post one issue per answer - that would help us focus on specific items one at a time.

Comment: These look great so far! Nice work to everyone involved in creating and testing them!

Comment: Can we cross-post from the previous feedback request question?

Comment: This is wonderful! Also, not sure if this should be its own issue as a proper answer, but I've noticed something weird (Chrome Beta): When hovering over `visited N+X days, X consecutive` line, my cursor displays an overtype tooltip, and changes into an interactive tooltip only after I click on it.

Comment: @Unihedro - beta versions are not supported... could be a bug there. Once it is out of beta we can revise.

Comment: Nice Job! I love specially the badge progress tracking feature. So usefull!

Comment: Now, if you really want extra work, you might want to make it compatible with IE 8 . Again, this is just extra work.

Comment: @Oded should site specific bugs be posted here?

Comment: @Tim - if they are indeed site specific, might as well post them on the site specific meta.

Answer (score 51):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) See [this answer by Nick Craver](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369002/331508); tl;dr - GDPR compliance.

---

### Age is no longer listed in our Profile view.

We can still enter our birth date in our profile, and it's listed under "Public Information":

[image]

However, our age is no longer visible anywhere on the new Profile page:

[image]

I believe this is a bug. Thanks to [rlemon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/22702474#22702474) for pointing it out.

Comment: For someone like me who is A) forgetful and B) always on Stack Exchange, this feature was the easiest way to figure out how old I am.

Answer (score 39):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It is not possible to obtain the **Informed** on child Meta sites (except [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com)), yet one can still select it as a possible "track next badge" option:

[image]

Clicking on "Go get it" takes you to the main site tour page.

Comment: I can do one better: I got it auto-selected as my next goal...

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291346/informed-badge-on-meta did as well.

Comment: @Deduplicator What should I say then? My tracker page wants me to get the [Hacker badge](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/no-we-have-not-forgotten-about-the-hacker-badge/) next!

Comment: It still asks new users to obtain the `informed` badge on the child meta sites.

Answer (score 34):

My next privilege is 1000 - I get the vote count and a VIP usercard:

> [image: Next privilege from profile screenshot]

HU? VIP usercard? [Privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/) doesn't say anything:

> [image: Privileges page 1000 rep section]

Ahh, a Help Centre search comes up with the [Expanded usercard section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user):

> [image: Help centre Expanded usercard section]

But the letters VIP are not mentioned anywhere on that page (I did a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>).

This is the only place I saw the phrase VIP usercard - and it doesn't even fit in. I think this should be changed to Expanded usercard - or even dropped completely.

Comment: +1 This is one of *many* cases where site behavior has been determined/explained in a meta post somewhere but is not explained at all on the actual site.

Comment: The reason it has to be like this is actually... Okay, fine.  It was a cheap hack: "VIP" fit, and "Expanded" didn't. Well, at some point it fit.   Now neither fits.  We'll take a look at options.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jaydles If there's more than one perk, just add "+1 more..." or "+2 more..." or whatever.

Comment: @Jaydles Do we have any update on it?

Comment: @Tim, it's in an "actual things we're banging through" queue. So, no update on timing, but it's not a "maybe someday".  :)

Answer (score 33):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I've noticed some weird bugs when viewing users' profiles; more specifically, the "rarest" badges at the bottom of a user's profile are sometimes completely absent.

This seems to be odd in who it affects and be random in places.

On SO meta - [Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s Profile

[image]

On SO - [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s Profile

[image]

On SO - [web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki)'s Profile

[image]

Could this be due to having more than 3 which are classed as the rarest and therefore breaking the code to generate whatever the top 3 are meant to be?

Comment: Which of these badges is wrong, or which section is missing what badge? I'm afraid I don't have badge rarity memorized.

Comment: Well, it's saying that users have badges but none of them are classed as the rarest. For example, web-tiki example is showing 87 bronze badges but 0 are classed as the rarest whereas the silver and gold badges are showing.

Comment: I have one gold badge on [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/16953/troyen?tab=profile) and it's not showing for me.

Comment: I think this is a *filter* for badges within each bucket that meet a "rarest" check.  It would be more logical to *sort* by rarest in that category.  (Alternately, we could just drop the filter in cases where total in a category is <4.)  We'll take a look.

Comment: I think that'd be cool. Just seems odd for Jon Skeets account where he has >5000 badges but none are classed as rare

Comment: Same [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi?tab=profile). However, there shows up exactly one bronce badge at least, so not completely absent. While there are several other bronce badges I've earned that certainly are rare.

Answer (score 33):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

## Marshal / Deputy progress shouldn't be shown to moderators

Moderators are recommended to get the unobtainable<sup>†</sup> Marshal (and Deputy I assume) badge. It was the default selection for me:

[image: screenshot of JohnB's profile]

[image: badge progress selection]

I think this selection should probably be excluded for moderators.

---

<sup><sup>†</sup> *If they don't already have it.*</sup>

Comment: Moderators cannot raise flags?

Comment: @TylerH they can, but unless you obtain Marshal/Deputy before you are elected/appointed, you cannot get the badge. You can see that I have 144 flags raised, but [do not have the Deputy badge](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/8708/johnb?tab=badges) (80 required).

Comment: That sounds like a bug in site behavior. You should still get the badges for flags acted upon by other moderators. Your personal user status shouldn't affect that.

Comment: @TylerH you're not alone in thinking that. Relevant feature-request: [Count flags handled as a moderator toward Deputy and Marshal badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138760/216955)

Comment: Thanks, we'll be removing these for moderators soon.

Comment: @JohnB Actually, that's a different feature request (it asks for *handled* flags to be counted towards the badges instead).

Comment: @MartinBüttner The badges are only for helpful flags anyway, so that means flags have to be handled first.

Comment: @TylerH No I mean that post suggests that the flags handled *by that moderator* should be counted for *that moderator's* badges. (At least that's how I read it.)

Answer (score 30):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - we may revisit this at a later date.

### Allow us to default to the Activity page rather than the Profile page

A lot of times, when I'm going to someone's profile, I don't care about their website, location, age, profile description, etc. I care about their posts, their edits, their activities. This now takes another click to get to the "good stuff", so could we have a setting to let us default to the Activity page?

Comment: They have this for moderators now.  Can they simply remember which tab we were on last?

Comment: Because this got declined, I wrote a [userscript](http://stackapps.com/q/6267/25384) that can be used as an alternative.

Comment: @Troyen That request was made [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253663/215485) :)

Comment: We have now got two profile pages: the "nice" one and the "useful" one. Which one people want as default? You've got one guess. _/sarcasm_

Answer (score 29):

As this thread has been [locked and abandoned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/253450/2), I've raised this issue in a [separate post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254052/cant-track-tag-badges-without-20k-rep).

---

I was dismayed to find that badge progress is unavailable for tag badges<sup>1</sup>.

When I heard of the badge-tracking feature, I was excited to begin tracking my progress toward the gold javascript badge:

[image]

So, I clicked the cog in the badge widget to configure my *Next Badge*...

[image]

... only to find that my desired badge was unavailable:

[image]

[Kendra](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/266735/kendra) notes that, according to [the blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-ones-big/?cb=1):

> Once you’ve earned all the privileges, the “next privilege” bar automatically starts tracking your progress toward your closest tag badge (or another one of your choosing).

So, tag badges aren't treated like other badges; you have to earn 20k rep before tracking them... in a separate widget... which is both unexpected and disappointing.

I imagine that design discussion went something like this:

> **Engineer**: Are we really going to put *all* these tag badges in the unfiltered *select your next badge* view? That's going to cause a
> performance hit. 
> **Designer**:
> That, and it's really going to clutter the view. By the way, I need something to put in the *next permission* space once a
> user has all permissions. I hate wasted space... 
> **Unicorn**: Guys, guys... two birds
> with one stone! We'll track tag badges in the space used for *next
> privilege*... and since they'll need 20k rep, that's only
> like 1% of our users who will ever potentially see it! Performance hit
> averted and, as a bonus, we can promote this feature as a "reward" for high-rep users. It all hangs together so *perfectly*! #guitar-riff #rainbow-trail

Unicorn's solution, while certainly expeditious *and* spin savvy, leaves a bit to be desired. I'd suggest one of the following:

- Add some UI cue which indicates to the user that suddenly tag and non-tag badges will be treated differently... you know... just for this aspect of the site... for some unknown reason.
- Simply add tag badges to the whole badge-tracking feature instead of setting them apart. Maybe filter by favorite tags or offer a 6th tab? I personally don't care that I won't have a *next permission* to track at 20k. There will still be plenty of badges... in the badge tracking UI. Just put a "you're awesome" sticker in the *next permission* slot.

<sub><sup>1</sup> I'm referring to [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/621962/canon) on [stackoverflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gspib.png) (not a child meta site) in case that's not clear from the javascript tag. I only have ~18k rep.</sub>

Answer (score 29):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - the congratulations should only display if you've actually been awarded the tag badge.  Also, tracked tag badges should award in more "real-time", i.e. when you visit your profile after a small hiatus (10 minutes, currently), we'll recalculate the counts and award if you've reached the threshold.

### Next Badge can't decide if I've earned the next badge or not

When I go to [my dba.SE profile](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand), I see this:

[image]

When I click <kbd>Track the next one ></kbd>, I see this:

[image]

The first state comes back after 10 minutes or so, and then I wash, rinse, and repeat.

I assume this is some kind of caching or synchronization issue between notifications and actual awarding of badges.

Noteworthy: even though I've been notified about 10 times today that I've earned the security badge, it still doesn't appear in [my list of badges](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand?tab=badges).

Comment: I've seen the same issue, and in my case too it's with a tag badge that I'm really close to earning.  Perhaps it's some algorithm that's rounding up the 92/100 into a 100/100 or something?

Comment: Actually I have a more plausible explanation for it.  I think badges are only awarded once a day, and yet you might still have met all the qualifications for earning a badge before then.

Comment: Same here - I was missing 1 upvote on a tag and when I got it, the profile was all "yay congrats well done" ...I thought "oh wow, they changed the daily tag score recalc too?!" ...and then was all disappointed when I saw my tag score was back to 99/100 after clicking "track the next one".

Comment: When I clicked track the next one and selected "Let's choose" it just selected one for me.

Comment: @james it's probably because you clicked for the first time *after* the badge was awarded (which happens daily for several badges). I think there is a sync issue where part of the system knows you've earned the badge, but part of it doesn't.

Comment: On my todo.txt for tomorrow.

Answer (score 28):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**Recommends unobtainable Excavator badge**

I'm in the Health.SE private beta, and the Activity page is recommending the Excavator badge:

[image]

The site has been [live for 14 days](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/health), so Excavator is definitely unobtainable at this point. It would make a lot more sense to recommend Suffrage in my case.

Comment: @Oded Are you sure the fix didn't impact other sites? See [this meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292206/1064325).

Comment: @falsarella - might be related, I am still looking.

Comment: @Oded Thanks! The [problem has been resolved](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/292393/1064325).

Comment: @Oded Not in the Open Source.SE private beta. It wants me to excavate the core of the earth!

Answer (score 27):

[image]

Four problems here:

1. Clicking the badge brings up this pop-up containing the same content as the hover-text. Great for mobile, but this was on the desktop.
2. The hovertext still exists. I like hovertext. Kinda pointless with the pop-up though. Especially when they both show up, stacked.
3. No matter how many times I click this thing, I can't get to the actual badge page. The pop-up just keeps popping up. Ctrl-clicking won't open it in a new tab either; just shows the pop-up.
4. If I grudgingly right-click and select "open in new tab" from the menu, I *still* don't get the badge page because the badge ID is wrong: there's no badge with an ID of 0.

Comment: Did you not draw a #3 on the image or am I going blind...

Comment: #3 involves typing / clicking. There's no representation of that in the picture.

Answer (score 21):

Feedback (not a bug report):

I would still like to see some sort of weighting for the "top network posts" section, as I [explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244460/162102) on the earlier post.  Right now this is a list of top posts by raw vote count without any other influences, so naturally it's going to show posts from the largest (or most-voting) sites I participate on.  Yet I've made contributions that, *by the standards of their communities*, are way more significant ("top") than some of my top posts.  The site where I have the most posts and am also a moderator doesn't show up on my list at all; that feels wrong.

I can exclude whole sites from the list, but that's not what I want either -- I'm looking for better balance, not wholesale exclusion.  So my request is to come up with and use some sort of low-impact per-site weighting factor, like we already have for hot network questions.

Answer (score 20):

### Sync the width of rep update boxes

[image]

The above is a picture taken on an inverse color environment from my [actual profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3622940/unihedro?tab=topactivity).

Answer (score 20):

<sub>Originally posted here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6087/3094</sub>

[image: Quack]

The word *consecutive* is truncated. It is awful. Please please please pretty please with sugar on top fix this. `:(`

<sub>*My system:* FF 37.0.1, Fedora 21, 64bits, all updates applied so far</sub>

Comment: Don't visit tomorrow. Problem solved. ;)

Comment: @Oded: ooh that's naughty. `:)`

Comment: Suppose they fix it now. It will just break up again when you reach 10000 days. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: in that case, I'll prod these guys in 27 years. `:P`

Comment: @PauloCereda -- well, since i missed a day, being on an airplane, my view hasn't got a total of 8 digits, only 5.  so it must be a function of length of that line vs. width of provided "box".  that has happened before in other situations -- maybe the "management" isn't expecting such devoted followers as you.

Answer (score 16):

### Tag score <sub><sup><sup><sub>too small</sub></sup></sup></sub>

Unresolved request from [this report in the old question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features/250445#250445).

Would you please increase the font size of question count by tag (and badge count) by 1 or 2 points? It's very straining on the eyes to read the numbers.

I have included an older design from Anime & Manga for comparison.

> [image]

Answer (score 16):

The user card has a feature that pulls important(?) links from the profile description and shows them at the bottom.

From [How does the User Card popup work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104810/7586):

> if you include a twitter, google plus, linked in, or facebook those links are prioritized.

[image: user card]

This feature ignores the new GitHub and Twitter fields in the profile - If I want the links (and I do), I need to embed them in the description as well.

The homepage is already there - thanks!

Answer (score 16):

### Please add creation date and last-seen date to activity page

Or at least the moderator-only block, if not the page in general.  Investigating accounts that seem to be *rather related* to each other has become harder with the new design because of the extra clicks.

As a user I often want to see this too, but, ironically, as a user I'll see it on the first page I go to.  As a moderator I definitely want to see the activity page, not the profile page -- so thanks for that change! -- but it does cost me these two bits of important information.  May we please have them there too?

Comment: This is one of the most important pieces of information for me when looking at user accounts and that extra click is a pain, which is part of the reason why I wasn't at all that glad that moderators default to the activity page anyway. But ok, if it would at least feature this important information, I could live with it, well, together with registeredness, of course.

Comment: @ChristianRau for me, that and "all actions", to get a view of what this user has been doing lately, are both very important, and they're on different pages right now.

Answer (score 14):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) - this is standard in all our post listings. If a post doesn't have a year, it was asked within the last year.

---

It is not entirely clear

in what year

this badge I did earn.

[image: What year did I earn this badge?]

Comment: Probably because you earned this badge back before time existed you dinosaur. (2.9)

Comment: Time worked differently before 1970, man.

Comment: It's all over Stack Exchange. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22678/add-year-to-time-date-stamps) and many more.

Answer (score 12):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) - this section of the profile would have been incredibly busy if we retained all bits of information on the mobile version. We decided to drop some of them in favor of readability.

---

Probably no bug, but I noticed that the new profile (in the mobile version at least) no longer has a "join date." Why was that removed, and is it possible to re-insert it? I find it relevant, or at least interesting.

This is for the regular mobile version, not the app.

Comment: Is "member for..." not what you're looking for?  That one's on the Profile tab, in the upper right?

Comment: That's a mobile only (on iphone at least) issue - maybe you are looking at the regular version? @Jaydles

Comment: @Oded: That is unfortunate. Some users, like me, use almost only mobile (from my phone), which means that the new profile is prettier, but quite a bit less useful. The "last seen" in particular steered a lot of my actions. I'll probably have to use the desktop version on my phone, which is kinda counterproductive. :(

Comment: @Oded: I think both pieces of info, and a 3rd, would neatly fit as a line under the 2 lines having the rest of the old info answers - website. In any case, "last seen" is more useful info than a non-site related web page, so one could, or could have, placed it there too.

Answer (score 12):

This is from Ask Ubuntu, but it affects any site with a link underline colour, including EL&U and U&L:

<kbd>[image]</kbd> <kbd>[image]</kbd> <kbd>[image]</kbd>

The link underline is going over the blue box.

It doesn't affect MSE because that has no underline on the text:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

This also affects the mini graph (although I can't take a screenshot).

Comment: Underline has more problems. If you hover above the small reputation graph on the Activity page on [Unix.SE], the underline appears between the month labels on x axis.

Comment: @Palec Yes, I was about to post that too. Will when I get home.

Answer (score 11):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Bug: Really rare badges not showing up in list of rarest badges

On the bottom of my [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2073257/daniel-frey?tab=profile), it says the rarest gold badge I have is "C++", but the "C++11" gold badge (which I have) is much rarer. Is there a threshold that prevents the badge from showing? If so, this doesn't work well together with the word "rarest" :)

This might be the same problem as @Stewartside reports or not - it's unclear to me what he means by "weird bugs".

[image]

Comment: Same here. 500 epic users? That's not rare, [\[promise\]](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4124/promise) is. This also may be related to the [missing rare badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253462/183280).

Comment: Same boat here over on SU, my rarest VBA bronze badge (1 of 1) doesn't show, but I'm not sure if it's rarest for site or rarest across network.

Answer (score 11):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) - if a post was created within the last year, we don't show the year. This is consistent across the different post lists.

Year missing from one of my top posts (which would lead me to think it was from this year, 2015, but we haven't gotten to Oct 2015 yet).

[image]

Comment: It's all over Stack Exchange. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22678/add-year-to-time-date-stamps) and many more. (so not part of the new profile page design)

Comment: @ShadowWizard that one you linked is about it when [so] started - not recently... He is saying that it's missing the year - surely it is? Other posts before Jan 1st have changed to '14 haven't they?

Comment: @Tim not sure,I see the year missing in other places as well. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard Here (on the new user page interestingly) it shows the year: https://askubuntu.com/users/186134/tim?tab=answers as well as here: http://askubuntu.com/a/562604/186134

Comment: @Tim yeah, quite a mess. But still, this is not limited to the new profile page hence likely rejected.

Answer (score 11):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - we decided to not add links in every possible location.

I've noticed that in the reputation panel, surprisingly few things link to the reputation tab.

[image: Links]

I expected both the reputation and the delta counter to link to the reputation tab (especially since the reputation counter says "reputation gained since your last visit to the reputation tab".

Comment: @Oded in my opinion, the entire top half should be nested under the same `<a>` tag for reputation. (The "top x% overall" link needs some thinking). But it's not that much of a game changer :)

Answer (score 11):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It seems that the new reputation graph doesn't know that rep can't go below 1.

It happilly graphs negative reputation and numbers that don't match the actual rep if someone would have had <1 rep at some point.

It's probably not noticeable on most profiles, but there are some extreme cases:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/KQOCvWm.png]

While this is a bit funny, I think it should be fixed.

Comment: Good find :P Is this if you are down voted when at 1 rep or something else?

Comment: @Tim - seen on a different user profile, which I'd rather not disclose.

Comment: @Oded Fair enough :)

Answer (score 10):

[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) - looks like this is caused by overzealous ad blockers.

The GitHub profile integration icon seems to be missing on Stack Overflow:

[image]
[image]

Finally, a use for my Surface Pro 2's pen.

This may be due to server-side caching.  (I have cleared my browser cache and refreshed the page several times, so it isn't client-side caching.)

Comment: What site is this happening on?

Comment: works for me in SE

Comment: I see it on SO, so I would assume a caching issue if you're seeing the problem there.

Comment: Had the same problem and figured out that it was blocked by ABP.

Comment: It's "Fanboy's Social Blocking List" specifically that blocks it.

Answer (score 10):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - if that text was 12px and you had in the Millions (e.g. Jon Skeet) it would go over the line:

[image]

#### Mismatch of fontsizes of “people reached”.

[image: ~67k people reached]

The fontsize mismatch between *~67k, people reached* and everything below is irritating and as far as I can tell unnecessary. *people reached* can easily have the same font size as everything below, as it has only one letter more than *posts edited.*

Comment: If we increase the font size of "people reached", it won't fit for bigger numbers. The goal here is also to make the people reach stat different from the ones below.

Comment: @StéphaneMartin it only doesn't fit when you get to a 6 digit number: http://i.imgur.com/ZWIGhIk.png by then surley it needs to be using M (million) not K (thousand)?

Comment: @Tim: Which it does, see for example for [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft And to be fair, if that text was 12px it would go over the line: http://i.imgur.com/pXKdWXo.png

Answer (score 10):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - number of tag badges limited during initial display; you can now use the search text box to filter to a specific tag.

#### Next tag badge dialog UI slow for accounts with large number of tags

For users with a lot of tag activity (I have [2376 tags listed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters?tab=tags)), opening up the dialog to select the next tag badge to aim for can take a *long* time.

The AJAX request for the data only takes ~600ms to load, so this is an issue with the JavaScript code rendering the dialog box. Profiling suggests it takes about 2.5 to 3 seconds to render the dialog box letting me pick my next tag badge to aim for.

Switching between the tabs (*All* to *Gold* to *Silver* to *Bronze*) or searching for a matching tag can lead to more delays, the switch can take up to 17 seconds!

Perhaps I am an outlier, but maybe this needs some performance work to not make this dialog box take several seconds to be rendered?

Comment: Whatever gave you the idea that we are interested in performance? Seriously though - we will be looking at this.

Comment: @Oded: yeah, once the payload is in the browser it is no longer your problem, right? :-P

Answer (score 9):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - we may revisit this at a later date.

I had to go to my top 10 sites individually and add up my people helped manually like a filthy casual.

So the network profile not being updated as well is a bug.

Comment: @oded Thanks for going through all these and marking them up! My answer is tongue in cheek - I didn't actually expect the network profile to be updated as well - but I do hope its on someone's list somewhere.

Comment: Looks like this is a duplicate, and there's a SEDE query to find this.  Takes awhile to run though.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246194/is-there-a-way-to-get-people-reached-sum-across-entire-network-for-a-user

Comment: Here's the query itself: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/305411/is-there-a-way-to-get-people-reached-sum-across-entire-network-for-a-user?accountid=2114

Answer (score 9):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - we may revisit this at a later date.

The following icon in the new profile:

[image]

feels like a refresh icon in a browser's address bar, not a "member for.." icon. It does not represent that, I suggest an icon similar to the "users" icon in some SE sites, something like:

[image]

but with one person in the icon. I know it is way to silly to be considered, but just saying it.

Answer (score 8):

[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) - We don't show **tags** in a different way anywhere. In this case, next to the tag, we indicate that you have earned a **tag badge** for that tag (a bronze one, specifically). Tag badges are indeed rendered differently - with the badge class (bronze, silver or gold) before the badge name. These are *different* things.

Don't know its a bug ot not, alignment of the badge bullet(.badge3 class) is reversed

In activity top icon badge/positioning is reversed as of default pattern

[image]

Or is there any pattern when the symbol comes first and when the name of the badge comes first

Comment: I don't understand. Can you provide a screen shot of where it shows the reverse as well?

Answer (score 8):

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) - this was always the plan. To let people indicate *whatever* links they wanted. But of expediency (and so the new pages launch sometime *this* year), we started with a cut down version of the feature, with the most popular services first.

Why privilege Github over Bitbucket by having a special showcasing section for only the former? I personally somewhat prefer Bitbucket due to it's support for private repositories and Mercurial. It has also recently [launched](http://www.infoq.com/news/2015/03/bitbucket-snippets-for-teams) it's own equivalent of Gist, which was the main feature it used to lack in comparison with Github. While Github does seem to have a larger community and userbase, there doesn't seem to be any reason to not accept other code hosting service entries in the profile template.

The [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-ones-big) seems to suggest that you can add dedicated fields for any link:

> The new profile has dedicated fields for links to Github, Twitter, your Rick Schroeder Fan Fiction Tumblr, or wherever you have something to share.

.. but unless it's referring to the "Website link" field, this does not appear to be true.

Answer (score 7):

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) - we will be changing these to not use past tense anymore.

## 'How to earn this badge' popup uses past-tense when describing badges

The wording of the descriptive text on the 'How to earn this badge' popup is written as if I've already earned the badge, i.e:

> Edit**ed** 50 tag wikis

[image: How to earn this badge]

Can we remove any time/tense-based references from the badge descriptions here?

Answer (score 7):

If you have a number of "unread" content in the user profile, the "votes" tab doesn't fit on the screen horizontally:

[image]

It dangles to the bottom-right of wherever you hover over the other tabs. This happens on [TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6073/5764), but perhaps also on other sites. For me it doesn't on [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com).

Confirmed browsers:

- Google Chrome 42.0.2311.90 m
- Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.17691
- Mozilla Firefox 37.0.1

[image]

Comment: Any news here? I'm still seeing the same issue from time to time.

Comment: @PaulGessler: Nothing yet. I'll poke harder today...

Answer (score 7):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Thank you for your feedback, I pushed a fix, it'll be live after our next production build.

---

[The calendar for consecutive days has gotten worse](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290617/the-calendar-for-consecutive-days-has-gotten-worse?noredirect=1#comment178595_290617)

The consecutive day calendar formatting has gotten much worse. The previous version didn't have all this whitespace between cells.

[image]

For comparison, here are screenshots of the previous calendar:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6):

this suggestion on my meta stackoverflow profile [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3680831/a-b?tab=profile) makes no sense until it show people reaches(even zero/0 people have reached)

see near " `"People Reached" tells you how many people found your posts here while searching for help.` "
[image]

Answer (score 6):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) - this is not a privacy setting and we do explain that at the top of the hide communities page.

I alluded to this [in my other post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253544/261498) but decided that it was also worth raising separately.

When I go to any of the sites with the new profile page, there's an option to view my network profile, so I figured I'd view my profiles in another browser to see if the "hide communities" function was working.

On the *site itself*, it works. For instance, I decided to hide my profile on the Anime & Manga site, and I get the following when I view my profile on that site when not logged in:

[image]

Similarly, when I view my profile on the German Beta, the communities I've hidden aren't shown:

[image]

But there's a **"view network profile"** link, and [my network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/2187225/maroon?tab=accounts) shows *all* of my communities, regardless of whether or not they are hidden.

I'm not really sure if this is intended behaviour or not, but well, this would make it easy for someone nosy (and who is neither the user themself or a moderator) to find someone's hidden communities. While I don't care *too* much about people on other sites discovering my otaku tendencies, well, I'd much rather not have my (potential) participation on sites like Academia or on religion sites for all the world to see.

And well, this just seems a bit contrary to the whole point of being able to hide communities?

Comment: Hiding community is to limit the visibility of your association to a certain site, not really "disassociate" yourself from the community. The usual advice is to create a different account for the other sites which you don't want people to link back to you.

Comment: @nhahtdh: makes sense, but I wanted to point this out in case it wasn't quite intended.

Comment: @Oded, regardless of whether this is a privacy setting it seems odd that it should hide the communities in some profile pages but not others. I went through hiding a bunch of communities which I don't really participate in, in order to make my network profile page a bit cleaner, and the only thing it accomplished was to add a massive panel on my own view of my per-site profile page telling me which sites I'd hidden.

Comment: And when other users visit your profile pages, they will not see those communities. @PeterTaylor - that's the point of this feature.

Comment: @Oded, I was trying to change the appearance of my *network* profile page, and it didn't work. (I tested by viewing with an anonymous browser window).

Comment: @PeterTaylor - I understand. But that was never the intention of the feature (and we do say on the hide communities page that "Hiding a community means other users will not see it in your Communities list and Top Network Posts."). No mention of the network profile page.

Comment: @Oded, I think that expecting a general user to draw a distinction between "Communities list" referring to the list in the per-site profile page but not to the list in the accounts tab of the network profile page is nerdview.

Comment: @Oded [another one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253599/hidden-profiles-are-not-private-at-all)

Comment: @Sha - we will be discussing how the feature works. Don't know yet what the fix will be, but we will be talking it over in the team.

Comment: @Oded sure, but the question is dupe of this answer (peculiar, isn't it? :)) and you already marked this one as [tag:status-bydesign].

Comment: @Sha - if this comes up multiple times, it means there is a problem with our design... And we need to discuss that.

Comment: I believe this was fixed, here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253599/hidden-profiles-are-not-hidden-at-all/276930#276930

Answer (score 6):

This is a somewhat preemptive consideration.

Being a high-rep user on [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com) I am left with a view of only two possible badges to track: Socratic (gold) and Peer Pressure (bronze).

[image]

Assuming that one day I might obtain **Socratic**, that will leave me with only a **Peer Pressure** badge to track... indefinitely.

My thoughts on this:

1. I'm not really eager nor attempting to obtain such a badge. So, why track it at all?
2. Tracking it seems superfluous, as the tracker would go from 0/1 to 1/1 immediately when you delete a post satisfying the criteria. I guess the same goes for **Student**, **Supporter** and **Tag Editor** (maybe others as well).
3. What happens when a user has obtained all trackable badges?

The answer to (3) might be that some badges are awarded multiple times (**Socratic** included), and one can always just leave that as the "track next badge". But then why not include **Great Answer** or **Great Question** (or others that could be awarded multiple times) as well?

Answer (score 5):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - this is clickable and will bring up a popup describing the badge.

## Hovering over next badge remains mute

In the new profile, there is a badge section in which progress for the next badge is displayed. However, in contrast to the traditional hovering behaviour of badges which showed the actual purpose of the badge, nothing is shown for the next badge.

Request: Make the next badge hoverable with the traditional description.

(This feature would be nice for reasons of consistency ; clicking there will show all badges of interest with their descriptions, but again, the light-weight hovering still would be nice)

([Source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290336/all-new-profile-hovering-over-next-badge-remains-mute/290339#290339))

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - this will be with you in the next build. This probably happened due to you hiding Stack Overflow *before* your user there got deleted. We are now syncing up such deletions with the hidden communities list.

Everything on my "accounts" list [here](https://stackexchange.com/users/2187225/maroon?tab=accounts) is correct, although the fact that it shows communities I marked as "hidden" on my profile (when I view this on a browser I'm not logged in on) seems weird to me.

However, when I go to the "hide communities" page, one of the communities I have an option of hiding or unhiding is Stack Overflow.

[image]

When I click on the link here, I'm directed to an error page. The thing is, I remember deleting my Stack Overflow account after I realized I had little use for it; I left with, if I'm not mistaken, 106 rep.

When I tried logging in to double-check if I'd really deleted my profile, I got this page, so it can't be that I'd forgotten to go through with deletion.

[image]

None of the other sites I've deleted my profile from before are showing up in the "edit communities" page. (For instance, I used to have a profile on Skeptics, but there's no option to hide/unhide the Skeptics community.)

Comment: @Oded: thanks for the response, although the explanation seems weird to me: there was at least one community -- the economics beta -- I definitely dropped after the hide community options appeared (and to boot, I might have hidden it first), but I haven't had such problems with that one. I don't remember when I dropped Stack Overflow, but there's a chance it was prior to this.

Answer (score 5):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - we may revisit the design of this section at a later date.

It's not apparent that the bio is scrollable when there's enough content to overflow. There's a (non-standard, kind of hard to see because of the grey and large amount of space surrounding it) scrollbar, yes, but no other visual cues that there's more content.

[image]

Making it so that a line of text is cut off and adding a 1px border on `.about` fixes the problem nicely:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) - Not all badges are trackable. Most of the ones we don't show as trackable are those that tracking would impact performance.

---

In the new Profile you can take track of your progress on getting new Badges.

But some of the Badgeds are missing in the selection, e.g.: Announcer and Pundit.

I would like to know why I cannot select them in the Track and therefore the progress is not visible.

Comment: Not all badges are trackable. Most of the ones we don't show as trackable are those that tracking would impact performance.

Comment: @Oded, I think the following question would be "Of those that are trackable, why are they not listed"?

Answer (score 5):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) - badge progression is closer to "real time" than the awarding of badges. So, we know the criteria of a badge and whether one has reached it (so we can tell you that this is no longer a badge that can be tracked and to congratulate you on earning it). But this is a separate mechanism from actually awarding the badge (we have separate schedules for the different badges - done for performance reasons). We will be looking at making the award faster for tracked badges.

I recently hit 600 question votes (out of ~1800 total votes), which should qualify for the electorate badge. That was the suggested next badge on my new profile page and, as expected, vanished after hitting 600. While the suggestion changed immediately, the actual badge took a while to show up.

It shows up on the suggestions with a check mark:
[image: Badge suggestions showing electorate checked]

But the badge page does not show it checked:
[image]

I had received other badges since qualifying for electorate and they seem to show up in both places, but the screens were still out of sync.

Why would the two screens show different statuses for a badge?

Answer (score 5):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - we don't have default tab choices anywhere else on the site (that's why they have different URLs, which you can link).

#### Use the current tab and last used tab OR use a "favorite" tab when viewing/switching between profiles.

Right now, if I go to a profile such as [this one](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/5498/randy-jones), it defaults to the "Profile" tab. I can click on the "Activity" tab and it will pull it up as it should. Now, if I click, "Meta user" I expect to be taken to the "Activity" tab of the Meta profile, but instead it goes to the default "Profile" tab.

The same goes for when I view a different user's profiles. If I am on the "Profile" tab and then open another user's profile, I expect to view the same tab that I was just on, but with a different user's information. Instead it always goes to the "Profile" tab.

The other option is to allow users to set a default tab for viewing profiles, either "Profile" or "Activity". This way we can always see the tab we want to when we view user's profiles.

I bring this up because personally I find the "Activity" tab much more useful for my purposes and always end up switching over to it when I view user's pages.

Comment: @Oded Any reason *why* this was declined?

Comment: There's [a userscript workaround for this on StackApps](http://stackapps.com/a/6268/7653).

Comment: We have now got two profile pages: the "nice" one and the "useful" one. Which one people want as default? You've got one guess. _/sarcasm_

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

#### The "new privilege" announcement doesn't contain a link.

[image: Regular pointer -- not a link]

I would expect it to contain a link that i can click to learn more about the privilege.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to this new feature, I'm able to now track daily reputation on Meta Stack Overflow via the Epic or Legendary badges, which is a pretty nifty side effect.

I did notice, however, that if you get a negative total rep score while tracking one of those two badges, the bar fills in.

[image]

Shouldn't the bar...*not* fill in?

Answer (score 4):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) - not all badges can be tracked. We had to drop a few where tracking would cause unacceptable performance issues.

[image: Convention badge does not show on the new Badges sections]
I have to say that the new badges section looks great. But then I notice that there where some badges that where not showing up there like **Convention**

is this a bug or is there a reason why **Convention, Talkative** and others are not there?

I looked in all the categories for them but I could not find them

Comment: You already have Talkative, so I wouldn't expect it to show up in a "next badge" tracker. Also some of the event-based badges can't really be worked toward, you either do that thing or you don't, so I don't expect things like Convention to be in a "next badge" tracker either.

Comment: You are on the "Available" tab. Click "All" and try again.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Convention ("*10 posts with score 2 on meta*") sounds very much like a work badge. In contrast, Investor - 0/1 (offer a bounty) is more like an event badge?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I do have Talkative but its not on the list event when you look at all. if you look for 'Outspoken' you wont find that one ether

Comment: Sorry, I confused Convention and Caucus.

Answer (score 4):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - we may revisit this at a later date.

The Your Comminities in the sidebar should be the same as the one in the Stack Exchange Dropdown:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: In lieu of an automatic change, you can manually edit the dropdown list to add or remove communities.

Comment: @HDE226868 I'd like to be able to chose which appear, in what order, rather than just be able to hide some though.

Comment: @Oded okay, fair enough :)

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - with you in the next build.

Filtering and sorting of the posts list on a user's profile (the external-facing page) is not preserved when returning directly to the page via the back button:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Kind of annoying.

Answer (score 4):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - we appreciate that you are finding this layout difficult, but will not be changing it in the short term.

### Feedback: Top Tags emphasis doesn't work for me

[image: Top tags screenshot]

When I look at this, the three tags which I see at first glance are the first, second, and fourth. The alignment effectively hides the third one, giving a misleading emphasis.

Answer (score 4):

Could we update site-logos/favicons to also use scalable vector graphics (SVG) on the profile pages?

[image]

<sub>Related feature request: [Favicons in top-bar dropdown not SVG](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253635/168244)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

---

[*Asked as a separate question*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253548/256282)

The old user pages showed if a user was unregistered, but I haven't been able to find that note on any users with the new page. Now it's possible that no one is using the sites I've been checking without registering fully, but it seems unlikely - I've checked a lot of 1 rep users!

This was a useful piece of information to have, as it gave a strong indication as to whether a user would even return. This is helpful for considering whether to spend more effort to improve questions or just to close them, for example.

Can it be added back?

Comment: I find the reasoning to be bad. Questions should be improved/closed on the post merit - not whether the OP will return or not. If the question is good enough to warrant editing, that's what you should do. If it isn't you should vote to close it. Don't forget - we are trying to help more than just the OP - we are trying to be a resource to everyone.

Comment: @Oded Consider a poorly written question which has a close but not perfect duplicate. If the user was around you can work with them to improve the question and make it distinct, if they're a drive-by user it's better to just close as a duplicate. Duplicates are much less frequently reopened, so knowing how likely it is that the user will return helps me decide how to act on the question.

Comment: @Oded  When I see a new user doing weird things instead of just deleting their unneeded post (this happens often), I either (1) point out the delete button under the post; or (2) explain how to register account, to be able to delete. Which explanation to give depends on the user's status, so I go look at their profile to find out...

Comment: @Oded One reason to know is when a post needs deleting. Only registered users can delete their posts; it's confusing for an unregistered user to be told “click the delete button”, since they don't get a delete button. Of course, it would be simpler for everyone except maybe SE developers to remove the distinction between unregistered and registered users altogether.

Answer (score 4):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) - These are sorted by the combined completion %ages of both bars (I don't think there is a reasonable secondary sort to this), given that both parts are required in order for the badge to be earned. In that respect the three highlighted badges are all 5% completed (2/20 == 10% - the other bar is 0% - so together 5% complete, 5/100 == 5% + 1/20 == 5% - so altogether 5% complete).

---

The **Select your next badge** dialog doesn't sort the tags as expected.

I would expect the tag with score 5 come before the tag with score 0, since it is more likely I will hit that one first.

[image]

Comment: These are sorted by the combined completion %ages of _both_ bars (I don't think there is a reasonable secondary sort to this). In that respect the three highlighted badges are all 5% completed (2/20 == 10% - the other bar is 0% - so together 5% complete, 5/100 == 5% + 1/20 == 5% - so altogether 5% complete).

Comment: @Oded Thank you for this formula as without this I had heck of time in figuring out. +1 Patrick for bringing this up.

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

## Pluralization bug at "posts edited"

When you've edited 1 post, the Activity tab says "1 posts edited":

[image: 1 posts edited]

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

## Mismatched numbers

[image: BUG!!!]

My badge progress bar says I've edited 61 posts. But in the Impact section, I've edited 62 posts.

Comment: Probably caching, but interesting nonetheless.

Comment: Could be that the new counter counts tag wiki/excerpt edits while Strunk & White doesn't.

Comment: @senshin I have have never edited a wiki post (at least not on StackOverflow).

Comment: @DominatorX Tim is not talking about your browser's cache.

Comment: @DominatorX He means a tag wiki, the description of a Tag, not a CW post.

Comment: I can edit the description of a tag?! :o

Comment: Probably not a bug. Multiple edits to the same post or any edits to your own posts don't count towards the badges.

Answer (score 3):

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) - we will be looking at the mobile design as a whole, as a separate project.

The back and forward button in the answer list looks weird on the mobile website:

[image]

Comment: What browser/OS (and versions)?

Comment: I am using iOS 8.3 @oded

Comment: @Oded: Okay, but I am sure this was okay a few days ago. Sure this isn't related?

Answer (score 3):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - Other numbers on the site are not intended as approximations, but are shortcuts due to lack of space - if you hover over that reputation figure, it tells you exactly how much reputation. People reached is not and cannot be an exact number.

---

How about removing the `~` (tilde) from the "people reached" number in the IMPACT box?

[image]

So instead of showing `~39k people reached`, drop the `~` and just show `39k people reached`.  Everyone will still know that "39k people reached" means "approximately 39,000 people reached" and not "exactly 39,000 people reached".

It will make it consistent with other areas of the user interface (I'm not aware of anywhere else in the user interface where the tilde is used).  For example, consider user reputations:

[image]

It doesn't show `~237k`, it just shows `237k`.

Comment: Other numbers on the site are not intended as approximations, but are shortcuts due to lack of space - if you hover over that reputation figure, it tells you _exactly_ how much reputation. People reached is not and cannot be an exact number.

Answer (score 3):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - we too had this idea, but there isn't a good location to link these to at the moment. We will certainly revisit this as and when such a link target will exist.

---

The new profile view is really good. It shows more better picture of profile. I just noticed one thing I am not sure previously it was available or not  but It would be good user experience I think.

Currently on user profile we see gold,silver and bronze badge count, but when we click one of these count nothing happens.

For examle,shouldn't it show gold badges user earned if user clicks the gold badge count?

[image]

Comment: @Oded it will be a good user experience. Do consider it

Answer (score 3):

This is a modification to the existing design rather than a bug report, according to me, scrolling the username with the profile description looks odd to me ... For example...

[image: Profile]

Also, why we have borders on tabs when zoomed out at 90%

[image: Tabs]

Answer (score 3):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) - [This post explains the methodology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here), as well as its constraints. The most relevant to this issue is that we can't easily track whether views on a question came before or after an answer was posted. But the method is designed to make it fairly uncommon to get an answer that meets the criteria for credit after a large number of views are already there.

---

Feedback: A new user can earn a significantly higher "people reached" number than users with more experience.

In her profile, a user whose initial post is a new answer on an old question, shows that she's reached ~7k people. A user, in this case, me, who's been active for months, shows ~2k.

If I understand the formula correctly, I imagine her number was generated based on the fact that she answered a popular question which has accumulated almost 7k views since its posting in 2011, whereas nothing I've done has attracted as much attention. Obviously this happens to many experienced users, and can be discouraging.

Her answer is equally as important, if not moreso, than any of my contributions. I'm not implying in any way that I'm more valuable; just pointing out what I think is a potentially negative characteristic of this statistic.

[image: Me]

[image: New user]

Comment: [This post explains the methodology](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here), as well as its constraints. The most relevant to this issue is that we can't easily track whether views on a question came before or after an answer was posted. But the method is designed to make it fairly uncommon to get an answer that meets the criteria for credit after a large number of views are already there.

Answer (score 3):

Diamonds in the list are rendered a little too high when viewed on my iPad:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - in the next build.

Wrong way to show membership length, probably linked to fixing [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253629/186983).

[image: error]

Comment: Just came here to add this one, looks a bit odd

Answer (score 2):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) - we removed some of the information on the mobile view as otherwise this section would be overly cluttered and unreadable.

On mobile (for iphone at least), "last seen" no longer shows - regular mobile, not the app.

This is quite helpful information (did user have an opportunity to see my comment/answer?, etc), so please make it available again.

Answer (score 2):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - as noted in comments, beta versions of browsers are not supported.

The tilde (~) in front of the numbers is a bit off in my font, and it looks like `-44`![image: -44 not ~44]

Comment: What browser (version) and OS?

Comment: Windows 7; Google Chrome Version 43.0.2357.18 dev-m (64-bit)

Comment: Development-version browsers are not supported. See [Which browsers are officially supported?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/168244)

Comment: I can't really downgrade, I'll just live with it then.

Comment: True. Just saying that this might not be addressed until it's reproducible in non-development versions of the browser (version 42).

Answer (score 2):

[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) - we have not been able to reproduce this bug.

Not sure if I should just edit my previous bug report or write a new one but I found another.

When I click on the days visited, the calendar pushes all of the content slightly downward. I'm using Chrome 41.

[image: Calendar bumps everything]

Comment: I can't repro this, which browser/OS are you using?

Comment: Can't reproduce with Chrome 41, Windows 7

Comment: @Oded, I'm using Chrome 41 on OS X and this bug shows up for me on Firefox 37 as well

Comment: @StéphaneMartin, ^

Answer (score 2):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - we may revisit this at a later date.

### Feedback: Profile configuration would be nice

Specifically, I would like to be able to configure which badges are shown:

[image: Screenshot of badge area]

I consider it a mild insult that the site is suggesting that I'm somehow associated with Strunk & White ([relevant discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135960/164922)), and would prefer to hide that badge.

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Can we capitalize the `r` in reputation (the first one) as seen below please:

[image]

All the other tooltips that start with a word have the first word capitalized.

Comment: *Only* the *first* `r`...

Answer (score 2):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - it is the average between the max and min values represented in the graph.

My rep graph shows numbers like 998 and 451. This annoys me so much - 998 is 2 off of 1000 / 1k and it isn't even clear what line the 998 refers to (the top of the grey segment or the bottom?).

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

My suggestion: Round to 1/100th of the rounded up number to 1sf:

Mine is 1,546. That rounds up to 2,000, and 1/100th is 20. Closest 20 is a reasonable number to round to.

Someone with 113,689 reputation would round to 100,000, and 1/100th is 1,000. So it would use steps of 1000.

---

Note that this is only the new graph in the new profile. The rep-tab graph is fine:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: @Oded could that number simply be rounded to nearest 10? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252803/reputation-graph-numbers-are-annoyingly-close-to-round-numbers

Answer (score 1):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) - we may revisit the design here at a later date.

## What are "X/Y score" and "X/Y answers"?

In the top left widget, it's completely unclear what the two "X/Y score" and "X/Y answers" are about or supposed to represent.

[image: example 1]

[image: example 2]

(OS X / Safari in case there should be a tool tip that isn't present.)

Suggestion (now that I grok it courtesy of the comments): make the tool tip appear when the two lines are clicked, much like the when you click the tag. Other possibility: relabel "Next tag badge" to "Next tag badge progress" or something to that order.

Comment: Do you see the text "Next tag badge" and/or a tag badge? Including a screenshot would probably be helpful.

Comment: @apsillers - more clear?

Comment: It's the score you have out of what you need. Same with # of answers. You need 70 more points and one more non-wiki answer on that tag for the bronze badge. Click on the badge and you will get a description. related http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253484/225304

Comment: Just to be perfectly clear: is it unclear to you *that* the meters are meant to be visually associated with the tag badge (which would qualify as a design issue) or is it unclear to you *why* the meters are associated with the tag badge (which is simply a misunderstanding of how tag badges are earned)?

Comment: @codeMagic - ah, ok. Thanks! Thoughts on the suggestion I just added?

Comment: @apsillers - it's unclear *that* the meters are associated with the tag, per my edit a few seconds ago. Design issue.

Comment: I can see how it's confusing but if you understand how those badges work then it's fairly straightforward, imo. But making the entire thing clickable I think would improve it.

Comment: @codeMagic: Indeed, it's missing context. Relabeling it to "Next tag badge progress" or something to that order would have nailed it too.

Comment: I do think that cutting in the line above it and putting "progress" might make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) – we [currently support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported) Firefox 36 and above.

---

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - looks like enough people are having this issue that I re-added the vendor specific CSS rule.

---

I hacked together a user script with a workaround:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        SE profile box-sizing fix
// @namespace   http://stackexchange.com/users/2330629/palec
// @description Adds a -moz-box-sizing declaration that fixes the broken layout in FF version older than 29.0.
// @include     *://*.stackexchange.com/users/*
// @include     *://*.stackoverflow.com/users/*
// @include     *://*.serverfault.com/users/*
// @include     *://*.superuser.com/users/*
// @include     *://*.askubuntu.com/users/*
// @include     *://*.mathoverflow.net/users/*
// @include     *://*.stackapps.com/users/*
// @include     *://stackexchange.com/users/*
// @include     *://stackoverflow.com/users/*
// @include     *://serverfault.com/users/*
// @include     *://superuser.com/users/*
// @include     *://askubuntu.com/users/*
// @include     *://mathoverflow.net/users/*
// @include     *://stackapps.com/users/*
// @run-at      document-start
// @grant       none
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==

// https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253734/238706
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing#Browser_compatibility
// https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    var styleText = document.createTextNode('body.user-page #content *{-moz-box-sizing:border-box}');
    style.appendChild(styleText);
    head.appendChild(style);
});
```

---

A day after the new activity and profile pages went network-wide, the whole layout broke down for me. I use a no longer supported browser (older Firefox), but this is so far the only thing that went really wrong.

Looking into the console, the problem is with the CSS property `box-sizing` that’s supported in Firefox only as of version 29.0. Till then, only the vendor-prefixed version had been available (since virtually forever).

**If you want to make me happy, change**

```
body.user-page #content *{box-sizing:border-box}
```

**to**

```
body.user-page #content *{-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}
```

**in `profile.css`.** This fixes the problem for me. I guess 27 added bytes are not a problem and they will make the difference between

[image: the boxes totally messed up]

and

[image: the boxes looking as intended]

for me.

Comment: I just want to add that the day the new profile pages launched, they looked just fine. The next day is when they started looking like the screenshot posted by @Palec. This should be fixed by the SE devs.

Comment: Which browser and in which version do you use, @Jeff? My old Firefox in not supported and I had known that before reporting, but hoped to get it fixed anyway. Maybe you reproduced the behavior in a browser that is supported. Anyway, if you care about fixing this, you might want to upvote this post.

Comment: Firefox 24. You can see a question I posted (a duplicate of this one) here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253740 ... To not support Firefox < 36 seems juxtapposed the universal dev mantra "compatibility first." I expect more from our gracious hosts whose entire schtick is dev Q&A.

Comment: Thank you for reconsidering, @Oded. Hope I can make the Internet a better place soon by upgrading my OS and browser.

Answer (score 1):

Everything lines up nicely with the margin on the sides except for the votes/points.

[image: Vote padding]

Answer (score 1):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) - see the [meta thread discussing it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/249988/140505).

Helpful flags are publicly visible. I'm not sure if this is an intentional change.

They weren't in the past. Flag weight *was* visible in the distant past. I think the decision to hide helpful flags when replacing flag weight was because too many people had been farming flags too aggressively.

Comment: This was already in [the previous iteration](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/249951/259867), live on Meta since February.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/249988/140505

Comment: @Sue I wasn't arguing for or against it, just pointing out that it was a change that I hadn't seen explained, which worried me. Now that Oded showed me associated discussion, I don't have really object to the situation. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

**"Last seen"** to be orange again (as in previous version) when a user visited not long ago

[image]

It was a bug that was later fixed in the previous version too, see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283681/seen-color-within-the-user-profile-changed-in-the-new-layout)

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - in the next build.

All of a sudden the period you've been around for has gone all weird. This applies whether or not you're logged in or if you're looking at someone else's profile.

[image: Member since today and for 2 years 10 months]

Answer (score 0):

The next recommended badge seemed to be always Critic after I got the downvoting privilege.

I got that in Computer Science and Puzzling, and I didn't even upvote once there yet.

If it is ordered by the progress, it should be a bug. If instead it just suggest me downvoting someone immediately after getting the privilege, isn't Supporter (for the first upvote) more preferable?

Comment: But you already have the up voting privilege when you get the down vote...

Comment: @Tim It always recommend me to get Critic, but never recommend me to get Supporter. Both have the progress 0/1.

Comment: Did you have the up voting privilege before the new user page or not?

Comment: @Tim For Computer Science, yes. For Puzzling, I registered after the new user page and got that immediately by association bonus.

Comment: That probably explains it then - it's likely to track the newest available badge.

Answer (score -11):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - *there is standard browser support to open links in other tabs. These are clearly links to external sites and we'd rather give users the choice (rather than take it away by forcing a new tab always).*

---

**Open new windows/tabs**

Please set the Website, Twitter and GitHub links in the Profile tab as target="_blank" so it opens a new browser tab on click.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken there is not a single link within the SE network that behaves like that. Changing it here would be counter intuitive.

Comment: Just middle click on it...?

Comment: @rene The rep league pages show up in a new tab when you click on the corresponding link in your profile.

Comment: In that case I'm mistaken...

Comment: @rene also the links in close/flag dialogs. :)

Answer (score -22):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

The grammar is incorrect for object pronouns:

[image: example of incorrect grammar]

The correct singular object pronoun should be him/her/them (if shared accounts are to be recognized).  I'm one person, so 'them' is incorrect in this context (even if it does appear 'awkward' to some).

The convention to use 'them' as a singular gender pronoun is convention, not proper grammar.  I know it sounds like nitpicking, but this *is* StackExchange where the correct form matters.

["There isn’t any way of using a singular pronoun to refer to someone without identifying that person as male or female.  When it comes to the third person plural, English only has gender-neutral forms such as they, them, their, etc."](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2012/06/he-or-she-versus-they/)