# "1 new answer to this question" websocket thing relocates the pagination controls inappropriately

Tags: bug, pagination, web-sockets

So I was reading some answers on the [new-profile bug-collation post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/), sorted by "active", and I got one of those nice websocket notifications telling me that there were new answers.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

So I clicked on it, and kapow! The pagination controls that are supposed to be right below the horizontal rule in the screenshot above got displaced:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

The pagination controls should probably stay attached to the top of the answer sections, rather than moving around when new answers are loaded.

Comment: I've just 'rediscovered' this bug ([PPCG meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13939/pagination-in-wrong-place-after-new-answer-loaded-in-place)) and it was pointed out to me that this report is over 2 years old! I understand that this is a low priority, but that's a long time