# Do the new user pages no longer show if a user is unregistered?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, unregistered-users

The old user pages showed if a user was unregistered, but I haven't been able to find that note on any users with the new page. Now it's possible that no one is using the sites I've been checking without registering fully, but it seems unlikely - I've checked a lot of 1 rep users!

This was a useful piece of information to have, as it gave a strong indication as to whether a user would even return. This is helpful for considering whether to spend more effort to improve questions or just to close them, for example.

If it's missing, can it be added back?

[*Posted to the master bug list*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253685/256282)

Comment: For mobile too please! :) (mobile is missing a fair bit of info currently)

Comment: If you've been checking on MSE, it may be because you can't post on MSE without registering (I think)

Comment: @Shokhet No I was looking on other sites.

Comment: All right; just making sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We are now showing whether a user is unregistered, on the profile page.

Comment: This should also be added to the activity page (at least for moderators), now that moderators default to that, since it is one of the most important pieces of information about a user.

Comment: @ChristianRau - yes, there are a few other data items that would benefit mods. I am considering where to put them all...

Comment: @Oded I see you've locked the other post now.  Do you want me to promote the feature requests there (one of which is about mod info, which prompted this thought) to new questions like this one?  Would that be easier for you?

Comment: @MonicaCellio - please do. I think such requests are better served where the community will actually see them (and not buried as answer x/100 in a thread no one will read)

Comment: Ok, will do.  I was trying to put them where you seemed to want them, but that made more sense when there weren't a hundred of them. :-)