# Should hidden community user profiles pop up in a Google search?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, search, google, hidden-communities

From another question related to the use of the Google search engine in combination with Stack Exchange, I found the following.

I have some accounts I solely use for flagging. Those profiles are set to hidden in my network profile. However, the user profiles do pop up in the search results in Google. And even worse, all those profiles put my actual contribution to page 17...

I know the sites hidden in your profile aren't really hidden, although this seems an unwanted side effect.

Can SE prevent the hidden profiles from popping up in Google? And if so, should they?

Comment: The problem is that [your network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/970966/patrick-hofman) is linked to from every site profile, and contains all your accounts. If they put `rel="nofollow"` on the network profile link it will solve what you describe, but would be "overkill' for those who do want their network profile to be indexed. So, not sure what I feel about it.

Comment: Indeed. That is why I tagged it discussion. I am not sure if there are caveats I missed. This is one I guess.

Comment: True. Another solution would be adding the `rel="nofollow"` in the network profile Accounts tab, on any sites you hide. Now this one sounds ideal, and quite easy to implement.

Comment: But would that solve the problem? Isn't it linked from a lot of other places, like user lists?

Comment: The /users page has `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` tag thus not indexed. As long as you don't post anything on those accounts, you should be safe.

Comment: This just confirms that the current implementation of the feature is entirely useless, there are too many trivial ways to circumvent it.

Comment: @MadScientist It's not promising complete privacy. I appreciate the ability to have people only see a few primary communities when they view my profile, as a way of controlling how I present myself.