# Hiding sites from Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, hidden-communities

I have few sites hidden for my profile and cannot be seen from browser page, but my problem it can be seen if someone checks my profile from Android App. How can I hide it?

Comment: This was only recently [fixed on the sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253599/hidden-profiles-are-not-hidden-at-all) but it was never meant to be private. I guess the app is lagging behind...

Comment: How shall I fix this? App doesn't show any available updates in play store. Current version of app - 1.0.85

Comment: *You* can't, because it's... a bug :D

Comment: But obviously you could hire yourself ;)

Comment: Nice joke  and hope someone would work on it.

Comment: Not really a bug. This is something that should be added, and since it's minor I doubt it will be done in the near future.

Comment: As the [question linked by rene](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253599/hidden-profiles-are-not-hidden-at-all) notes, hidden sites... really aren't. This is just one of the many ways in which they still fail to be hidden. The SE single sign-on model was never designed with hidden sites in mind, and as a result, the current bolted-on implementation leaks information like a sieve. It's *maybe sort of* OK if you just want to, say, hide your codegolf.SE account from you SO profile because you think it looks unprofessional, but you should *never ever* rely on it for actual privacy.