# Hidden communities not working in mobile?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, mobile-app, hidden-communities

I have the SE app on iOS. When I signed out and looked on my profile, I saw that the **communities that I have hidden** (Stack Overflow and Tor) **are shown.** Why does this occur, and will it be fixed? The app version is 1.6.6.

---

#### Screenshots:

[image: Picture 1]
*Hidden communities not hidden on iOS app*

[image: Picture 2]
*Hidden communities are hidden in browser*

[image: Picture 3]
*Hidden communities on profile (signed in)*

Comment: The apps use the API and according to [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276930/323179): "The API and Area 51 are more convenient methods for finding a user's hidden profiles than scraping every profile with more than 100 reputation." Therefore I think this is technically the expected behavior. It isn't the best behavior, though.

Comment: there are far more holes in that feature than this one, hiding communities is pretty much broken by design, it doesn't actually hide much.