# Is this a User Profile page CSS problem?

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, profile-page

There appears to be a User Profile page CSS problem. See screenshot, taken browsing with Firefox 24. Applies to all Stack Exchange sites, including Server Fault, Super User, unix.stackexchange, etc. Haven't checked any other browsers.

[image: SE user profile page css problem]

Comment: Your version of Firefox is too old.

Comment: I was waiting for someone to say that.

Comment: Reference: [Which browsers are officially supported?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/262755)

Comment: It appears that [this issue was already reported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253734/262755).

Comment: Ahh, good to know. Feel free to close this Question, if you want.

Comment: I'd also like to add that the new profile pages displayed fine in Firefox 24 the day they launched. This is a simple float problem and should be fixed by SE devs.