# Badge shows as earned when it isn't on new activity page

Tags: bug, badges, recent-activity

Today I looked at by user page on bitcoin.SE:

[image: Congratulations! Thanks to your efforts, you earned "transactions!"]

I click on "Track the next one >":

[image: Next tag badge: transactions]

...and it shows that I still haven't earned it.

I checked my badges, and I don't have the bronze `transactions` badge.

Comment: Strange. It says your tag score is only 96. Caching?

Comment: @mhlester I went through and added up the scores of my answers, and I get 167. http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+user%3A2306+%5Btransactions%5D None of them are community wiki, either.

Comment: Oh look at that. You've also got 100 answers, while your profile only says 43. Must be using the wrong criteria somewhere

Comment: @mhlester 100 answers? Where do you get that? I get 41.

Comment: Oh crap my mistake. I clicked the tag in your profile and it took me to search results. I added `is:answer` but didn't realize it was only searching for the text "transactions" rather than the tag

Comment: Looks like it's already reported here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253516/248072