# Bug Report Answer deleted after being marked 'status-completed'

Tags: discussion, support, profile-page

Were all the answers to the bugs report master list question  ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list)) were meant to be deleted after being marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) and it takes of the reputation earned by the answer?

I have seen many of them not been removed after being assigned [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Whats the purpose of assigning [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) if eventually post will be deleted and will not be seen by others? It will be discouraging for the people who put effort to make a report, add images and explain the problem to help community and them selves as well to get bugs resolved.

Or it was just a case for me, for instance my answer was ([link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list/253488#253488))

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Those kind of questions get very crowded with answers quickly. It really depends on the dev handling those if your answer stays or gets deleted. Looking over the 4 pages of answers, 29 posts with the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) got deleted so I assume that should be the expected action. The other OP's of the 20 [status-completed answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3A253450+status-completed) should expected deletion as well, maybe triggered by this answer.

I personally don't feel bad or happy about fake internet points. Users that do should keep in mind that voting is on the post (which has no feelings), not on the person. The voting on the bug reports should be considered as a way for the community to signal the priority to the devs, not as a way to indicate the usefulness of the answer.

Having seen this happen a couple of times I think a bit of advice to the dev-team posting those kind of bug report master list:
Please indicate on the question what your procedure will be for posted answers that get a status (like  [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)) so the community doesn't get surprised by the sudden deletion of upvoted answers and the reputations consequences. Maybe suggest posters to make their answer [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)?

Comment: i have updated your question and have deleted my comment that you addressed in your comment so that you last para addresses the question

Comment: I think thats exactly my point and i will wait if any one will confirm this :)