# 0 helpful flags doesn't mean I haven't flagged at all - please fix it finally?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page

So before the page redesigns I (and not only me I guess) got problems with being unable to get the flag summary without switching to address bar if I had no flags - the number was shown only if you have some helpful ones.

Since the page redesign the activity tab has a link to your flags which looks like "X helpful flags". But wait, it doesn't appear to be a link if I have some declined, disputed, aged out or active flags, but no helpful. Please make it be a link ***always***.

> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree! I thought that something went wrong with my flagging, and I almost flagged the question twice if I hadn't went to my flag summary manually through url.

Currently, I have [0 helpful flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1064325/falsarella), but I now have [1 pending flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1064325). But, since I have 0 helpful flags, I don't have a link to my flag summary (or flag history). That's the problem: the missing link on my summary almost made me send duplicated flags.

Comment: @Oded Bug related to new profile pages. *The [bugs and feedback list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253450/284991) is locked.*

Comment: @Firelord Indeed. Great point, but, no, the option is not greyed out. I don't know why, but I know I flagged it through `in need of moderator intervention` option.