# The self dupe hammer doesn't check whether I'm suspended or not and allows to close anyway

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, account-suspension

Dunno, whether it is a bug or not. Someone voted to close [my question as dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256371/0-helpful-flags-doesnt-mean-i-havent-flagged-at-all-please-fix-it-finally), and I used the [self-dupe-hammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes) to close it completely. I realize that it is Community who closes the question. But actually, it doesn't do it just because of wanting so. I force it.

However, I was suspended at that point of time, so I'm not sure, is it legal?

Comment: *marked as duplicate by rene, Shadow Wizard, Community♦*. Community isn't suspended. All you did was indicate that the dupe was indeed correct.

Comment: Legal? Sure. For someone so obsessed with minutiae, you pick a really incorrect word.

Comment: Nice catch! Well, technically the close vote is cast by Community user, not OP.

Comment: @Mart Yes, but it is me forcing it to close.

Comment: Agree it's a bug - anyway dupe hammer is reserved for users with gold tag badge, the self hammer is different thing. New tag might fit.

Comment: Rage self-duplicate-closing is nowhere near the level of rage deleting and defacing

Comment: @random Particularly given that another user would need to vote to close the question as a dupe first; one cannot self close as a dup out of the blue.

Comment: Welcome back, ya goof.

Comment: @Servy one can flag  his/her own question, if not suspended. (flag is enough for the self-close hammer no need in actual close vote)

Comment: @Won't Is it a new way to word-play, or... wat?

Comment: Nah.  Hope your vacation was relaxing :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hmm. Yeah, that seems fine.

There is no damage to the site that can be done this way, and if anything... a question staying open just because its owner is suspended sounds like a worse outcome.

I'll allow it.

Comment: Lol, good logic. Ok then :)

Comment: Turn a bug into a feature. Nice skill! ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard clearly one of the requirements for working there :P