# The new profile shouldn't mistakenly imply that you can earn the Informed badge on a meta site

Tags: bug, badges, profile-page

I just joined Sports, and I decided to take a look on Sports Meta. I clicked on my profile there. This is part of what I saw:

[image]

[The Informed badge is not selectable as a new option.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list/253486#253486) Yet the profile shouldn't indicate that it is, in theory. . .

This seems to be a bug.

Comment: @TotZam It's still showing up for me.

Comment: @TotZam I have Internet Explorer, and it works. I just tested it on Chrome, and that works, too. What OS are you using?

Comment: Why has this issue been resolved yet?

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed a bug, either server or UX, possibly server. I saw the same thing on [I can't take the tour on this meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11854/i-cant-take-the-tour-on-this-meta).

It came up that tours are important, which is why it should remain on new meta accounts.

A badge is offered, but not available. The link indicates a tour on a meta site, but redirects to the meta's main tour page, but the meta profile still invites the badge.

This is might remotely be a server setting problem with subdomain redirects in https, similar to the issue I raised here: [Apache .conf to redirect all http subdomains to corresponding https subdomains via wildcard alias](https://serverfault.com/questions/940097/apache-conf-to-redirect-all-http-subdomains-to-corresponding-https-subdomains-v).

It is more likely a UX bug, since many forums indicate that there should be no tour for meta, in which case main side code was ported to the meta site.