# What GitHub repo do I fork to contribute to bugs?

Tags: support, github

I have recently found an old bug on meta pages. I want to look into contributing a fix in the code. Since SE seems to be developed on GitHub, I want to know which GitHub repo governs the site, since SE has many GitHub repos.

Research & Background:
Stack Exchange has a *verified* namespace on GitHub with many repos, none of them clearly defined enough to know their role in relation to the website. The very presence of SE on GitHub, without saying "This is what this is and is not" (as Liquid and others do https://github.com/Shopify/liquid) implies *from the GitHub side of the web* that SE wants support from GitHub users in developing the services associated with the branding on the GitHub profile. Having a GitHub repo that doesn't say "We don't want help", and a Question answered in summary that SE may "Eventually, probably" go open source in the future ([Will Stack Overflow's engine be open sourced?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35/will-stack-overflows-engine-be-open-sourced)) reasonably seems as a contradiction needing clarification. Here it is (the name is "StackOverflow", but the namespace in the URL is "StackExchange" and it is a verified account): https://github.com/StackExchange

This is the bug I want to help fix: [The new profile shouldn't mistakenly imply that you can earn the Informed badge on a meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258179/the-new-profile-shouldnt-mistakenly-imply-that-you-can-earn-the-informed-badge/318704#318704)

Comment: @RobertLongson thank you. As I said, IMHO and I'm just the new guy. So, is this a dup question then?

Comment: @JesseSteele https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35/will-stack-overflows-engine-be-open-sourced or for your other idea https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215422/mandatory-comment-after-downvote

Comment: @JesseSteele if your original question had referenced that question and said something along the lines of "I see this old question <link to it> that appears not to have a definitive answer.. After so many years have you made a decision yet" I would guess you'd have got fewer downvotes. I can't be certain of course but at least those downvoting could not have been doing so because the question lacked research which is one of the reasons on the downvote tooltip.

Comment: For the record, I did search and couldn't find anything. It is somewhat difficult to find dups until posting a Q. I'm new and all, but I've actually searched Google to find more answers on the SO network rather than individual sites, prolly bec Google really is amazing. Just sayin' it's difficult. Difficulty of finding dups is a "thing", not just rookie's imagination, just sayin' respectfully. (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260231/should-rep-hunter-answers-be-downvoted)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The base code is not available publicly and you cannot contribute to it as a user. We use GitHub Enterprise hosted privately on internal servers, *not* the publicly accessible GitHub service.

We don't allow generic contributors, only employees. Getting more people involved involves [hiring more people](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here).