# In next badge selection, why does Epic with 2/50 sort ahead of Illuminator with 24/500?

Tags: bug, profile-page, daily-reputation-badges, badge-progress

Mostly, the badges are sorted in order of percentage complete, as far as I can see. But per the title, Epic (with 2/50, or 4%) sorts ahead of Illuminator (with 24/500, or 4.8%). What's up with that?

Comment: It was quite confusing when I saw that on my next-badge but I did figure out the math behind with the help Oded's formula.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [Oded's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list/253709#253709): (emphasis mine)

> [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) - These are **sorted by the combined
>   completion %ages of both bars** (I don't think there is a reasonable
>   secondary sort to this), given that both parts are required in order
>   for the badge to be earned. In that respect the three highlighted
>   badges are all 5% completed (2/20 == 10% - the other bar is 0% - so
>   together 5% complete, 5/100 == 5% + 1/20 == 5% - so altogether 5%
>   complete).

Please see Patrick Hofman's "[Select your next badge dialog doesn't sort the tags as expected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list/253709#253709)" post for more details and his next-badge screenshot. Also note that Oded's answer was given on the initial release of new profile where they were collecting feedback and bugs. The current next-badge UI looks little different.

Here a screenshot of my 'Epic' & 'Illuminator' next-badge section:

> [image]

Notice, my 'Illuminator' badge (1/500 ) is placed *after* the 'Epic' badge (0/50).

To obtain the **bar percentage** you will have to **right-click** on the **next-badge label / title**. For example,

Here is what my 'Epic' badge shows:

```
<div class="bar">
    <div class="label">Epic - 0/50</div>
    <span class="badge2"></span>
    <div class="percent" style="width: 0%;"></div>
</div>
```

Here is what my 'Illuminator' badge shows:

```
<div class="bar">
    <div class="label">Illuminator - 1/500</div>
    <span class="badge1"></span>
    <div class="percent" style="width: 0%;"></div>
</div>
```

So, if I apply Oded's formula i.e. 'Epic': 0/50 == 0% + the bar is 0% - so together 0% complete, and in case of 'Illuminator': 1/500 == 0% (only consider *integer* part on the left of the decimal point) - bar is %0 - so altogether 0% complete. So, both stood at 0% level and the badges get the default *alphabetical* sort order.

Now, lets apply this formula to Nathan's badges numbers. 'Epic' with 2/50 == 4% - the bar is 4% - so together 4% complete and in case of 'Illuminator': 24/500 == 4% (only consider *integer* part on the left of the decimal point) - the bar is 4% - so altogether 4% complete. So, both stood at 4% level and the badges get the default *alphabetical* sort order.

Comment: So, it's just truncation.

Comment: Yep, and see Patrick Hofman's post n shared next-badge screenshot and try to apply that with his 3 badges especially the 3rd one.