# How is the closest tag badge determined?

Tags: support, tag-badges, badge-progress

A feature on meta-sites (and apparently for high rep users) allows you to track your next tag badge.  There is a recommended tag by default, which is supposed to be the tag you are closest to completing.  How is this closeness calculated?

It seems to be based on both your current tag score and the number of answers provided, but how specifically does it achieve this?  I'm just curious.

---

<sup>For reference, [this question on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303058/4320665) inspired this question, and it also includes [my best guess](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303064/4320665) (which might be totally wrong).</sup>

Comment: You probably need to update the answer over meta.SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Oded's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list/253709#253709): (emphasis mine)

> [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) - These are **sorted by the combined
>   completion %ages of both bars** (I don't think there is a reasonable
>   secondary sort to this), given that both parts are required in order
>   for the badge to be earned.

Since you have not shared any next-badge score/numbers in the post, I would suggest read my answer [In next badge selection, why does Epic with 2/50 sort ahead of Illuminator with 24/500?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263829/in-next-badge-selection-why-does-epic-with-2-50-sort-ahead-of-illuminator-with/263865#263865) for more details.