# Sudden voting increase in 2015

Tags: discussion, voting, policy

As part of a research, I study StackExchange voting along time. Looking at the data - https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/356895/votes-in-2015, There is a sudden increase of(~15%) in the number of votes in mid April 2015 after a very slow year. There is also an increase in answers, comments and edits.

I examined the [changes blog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) and found no policy , feature or UI change that can explain it. What could be the cause for this sudden change?

[image: Votes graph in 2015]
[image: Posts graph in 2015]
[image: Edits graph in 2015]
[image: Comments graph in 2015]

Comment: You've not split by VoteTypeId...

Comment: I did, since most votes are up votes, most of the increase comes from up votes but there is also a down vote increase at that point in time

Comment: *This question pertains only to a specific site in the Stack Exchange Network.* (or have you noticed the same thing on other sites as well?) *Questions on Meta Stack Exchange should pertain to our network or software that drives it as a whole, within the guidelines defined in the help center. You should ask this question on the meta site where your concern originated.*

Comment: Well, the [new profile page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list) was launched network wide in April. Not sure how it's related but I don't think it's a coincidence either. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Probably that. Many users got "here's progress bar for your next badge, Electorate" -- even with "go get it" link to a list of questions.

Comment: @Norm yup, wonder if the team can come with some facts about it.

Comment: Can you show weekly averages?

Comment: @ShadowWizard could be an effect of [big burn down](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303898/sudden-change-in-voting-proportion#comment240443_303898) (and followed auto-deletions)

Comment: @gnat long shot, Norm's guess sound more reasonable. But hey, who knows?