# Allow moderators to choose their default user view

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, moderator-tools

Currently, the default user view for normal users is the Profile tab, and for moderators it's the Activity tab.

On sites I moderate, I often find the mod dashboard view for users to be more useful. I'd like to be able to set this so that it's the default view when I go to a user's profile page.

I'm thinking an extra option in the mod menu there:

[image]

This could also be rolled out for all users, if it's useful.

Comment: Moderators can convert users to hamburgers?

Comment: @SimonKlaver Of course. You wouldn't want us converting them to any *other* kind of burger, would you?

Comment: Have you tried using an XML parser instead?

Comment: @nicael That would require us to split the user into a collection of nodes. With regex, if we're going to parse a user then we can at least parse them *whole* and avoid using the "chop into little bits" option first. Even if Tony the Pony does occasionally try to impale us.

Comment: For all users would be [really really nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list/253659#253659).

Answer (score 10):

I have a counter-proposal that would address your use case too.  (And believe me, as a fellow mod, I'd take the same option.)

You know how some of the tabs on the "activity" page have sub-tabs?  For example (from my own profile):

[image: "all actions" with sub-tabs]

Those selections are sticky.  If you go to another user's profile and choose a sub-tab and then go to a *different* user's profile, the same sub-tab is selected.  If you don't like the current setting, you can easily choose another and it becomes the new default.  (This applies to other users; your own profile is different.)

Let's extend that idea to the top-level tabs: if I -- anybody, moderator or not -- go to some other user's profile and choose "Activity" instead of "Profile", assume that that's what I want to see for not-me users in general.  For moderators there's a third option, the mod dashboard.  Use the last-selected tab on that site until the user chooses a different one, just like for the other tabs on the page.  As with the current behavior, treat *your own* profile differently.  (SE does that now; you'll see your own Activity tab but everybody else's Profile tab, by default.)

This would let every user see the tab he -- from past practice -- prefers (changing it is one click away), and doesn't require adding any new configuration UI.