# Can Peer Pressure be removed from the "Next Badge" list?

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-progress

Under "next badge" it lists all the badges achievable for people to set as goals, however while most of them make sense as things you want to go out and get "peer pressure" seems out of place.

The only way to get the badge is to post an answer so bad that it gets downvoted to -3 so that you can then delete it. Not something we want to encourage.

I suggest either removing the badge from this list or only showing it if people actually have an eligible post to delete.

Comment: I'd go with the or-part of the last sentence: "or only showing it if people actually have an eligible post to delete"

Comment: Related: [New profile pages are out - bugs and feedback master list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253639/168244)

Comment: "only showing it if people actually have an eligible post to delete" is by far the best option IMHO; this badge is, presumably, intended to motivate people to remove a crap answer, and will probably help ... a little anyway ...

Comment: True. It's also more work though.

Answer (score -3):

Actually this might be something we want to encourage. Let's assume that the voting mechanism works, and that therefore a downvoted posts reflects its unfitness for SE standards, rather than rage/serial downvoting against a person. Personally, I don't agree that to get the badge one has to post a wrong answer deliberately. **Posting wrong answers can happen, and is part of the Q&A process.** A user who deletes their own answer because it was deemed wrong by the community shows that they understand how SE works and what the goal of the sites is: collect quality answers to quality questions. Deleting wrong answers is basically housekeeping. Positively reinforcing this behaviour with a badge seems fair to me.

Comment: However when I'm looking in my profile and trying to collect all the badges I'm actively looking for ways to do so. In order to get this badge (I have no downvoted answers) I would have to deliberately post a bad answer in order to then delete it after downvoting. That is not something we want to encourage.

Comment: Note that this list already leaves out unattainable things like the precognitive and things we don't want to encourage people to try for like tumbleweed

Comment: @TimB Why deliberately? [I have this badge](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure?userid=22140) and I didn't post a wrong answer deliberately.

Comment: Go to your profile, click on the gear next to "Next Badge". The site is giving you a list of targets to try and achieve, getting those badges. In that list is Peer Pressure. I have no questions or answers on worldbuilding with a negative score. If I'm trying to get every badge on that list then the only way to do so is deliberately to make a bad post.

Comment: Actually I tell a lie, there is one from when we were working out the site scope but it's on -2 and already deleted. I've none on -3 and that's the only one on negative.

Comment: Note that I'm not suggesting deleting the badge entirely. Just removing it from the "next badge" list

Comment: @TimB I undertand. I still don't think that the *only* way to get that badge is to deliberately post a wrong answer.

Comment: Ok, so you're a badge collector. You want to get the badges on the "next badge" list. You have no -3 voted posts. It comes up as your next badge. How do you get that badge without deliberately posting a wrong answer? Keep in mind that "next badge" is not badges you can get by accident. It's badges that you can go out and try to get. So what steps do you take to try and get that badge?

Comment: @TimB You don't. :)

Comment: Then you made my case for me. It should not be in that list - since the purpose of that list is to provide goals and by your own admission there is no valid route to achieve this goal.